# Cable clamp connector and knockout size for 6/2 NM and 8/2 NM

Tags: electrical

I'm running some cables for an electric tankless hot water heater. I haven't decided which one yet. It'll either need 2 x 40A, 2 x 50A, or 3 x 40A, all 240V (there are some that need 60A, but I'll pass on them). I plan on running two sets of 6/2 NM and one 8/2 NM from my breaker panel to some 4x4 metal boxes in the wall where I'll mount the water heater. That way, I can pick the breakers, and use the right two or three runs I need. Once I decide which water heater I'm using, I'll run FMC from the box(es) to the water heater.

I'm wondering what size cable clamp connector (and hence, knockout) I need for each 6/2+G NM cable and for the 8/2+G NM cable (I'm assuming no doubling of cables in a clamp). Also, can I have more than one (maybe even all three) in a single 4x4 box? Or would it be better to use two or three boxes?

Also, what kind of box(es) would I use? I'm only seeing 3/4 and 1" KOs, and I suspect I need something larger...

Comment: The biggest question I have is "why electric tankless hot water?"

Comment: 1) More energy efficient. 2) More space efficient. 3) No more burst tanks flooding when we're not there to deal with it.

Comment: Generally, I find electric tankless to be a poor energy tradeoff (don't make the utility spin up their peaker if they don't have to, modern electric storage water heaters are much better insulated than older units).  I do agree with you re: space and burst tanks, but unless gas is an absolute non-starter for you or you're on propane, you're better off going gas if you want tankless.  (Going to the gas side also opens you up to boiler+indirect setups, which have some very nice advantages...)

Comment: I agree with 3phase I have put a new service in for a customer that really wanted a tankless electric. After installing it then point of use small electrics to reduce the fluctuations he was not happy and went back to a tanked water heater he spent +10k with the new service and adding the point of use tankless. I have had gas tankless and it was ok. Another customer was less than happy because his bill jumped because monitored power was based on peak usage so that increased the rate he was paying for all of his power.

Comment: There is currently no gas (natural or propane). I'd prefer not to add it. I don't really want to deal with the venting requirements for gas (tank is not on an exterior wall). Thanks for the feedback. Perhaps I'll add the wiring for the future, and stick with a tank for now. Definitely something to consider.

Answer (score 2):

First, if it is at all possible to run **conduit** between panel and on-demand heater location, that's a great way to do it.  That lets you defer the wire size decision until you buy the heater, and simply drop in the individual wires you need.  Conduit allows higher ampacity from the same size wire - #8 is good for 40A in NM, but in conduit, 50A (single circuit) or 44A (2-3 circuits).  If the conduit is metal and non-flexible, the metal conduit provides the ground - no wires needed. A 1" conduit should be plenty.

Another option, since you need a box *anyway* and seem focused on a 125A heater, fit a 10x14" box **that happens to be a subpanel**.  Something like a CH8L125SP.  Supply that with #2 Cu or #1/0 Al wire or cable at 125A.  Then you can feed whatever breakers the heater needs at the time you select it.

If you want to do it as planned, you will need a LARGE box.  Each #6 wire needs 5 cubic inches and each #8 needs 3 cubic inches.  That is far too big for a 4x4 box. Consider at least a 6x6 box.

A 1" KO should be alright for a #6.  Use one KO per cable.

Comment: I did consider a subpanel but I'm not keen on running rigid conduit through walls and attic. I'm sure an experienced person could do this blindfolded, but as a novice, I was thinking a few runs of NM would be easier. When you say 1" KO, what is the clamp size (or if that's the clamp, what's the real KO)? I ask because a 3/8" clamp goes in a 1/2" KO, so I assume that continues as they get larger.

Comment: But, let's assume I do want to run conduit to a subpanel. 3@2 XHHW in 1" EMT is almost 37% fill - I'd have at least 2 90 degree elbows (up one wall, down the other). That sounds tight. Or since the WH doesn't appear to need neutral, can I just run 2? Any reason I can't do 1 1/4" PVC Sched 40? That has a fill of < 24% and is much easier to cut pipes to right size. I'd also want to use two pull elbows or LBs for the two turns if possible in order to have the conduit that runs across the attic flat on the joists. Any concerns? Attic run is about 12'. Run in each wall is 3-4'

Comment: Appropriateness of conduit depends on route... but actually, conduit is MUCH more novice-safe than bare cables.   See, you assemble it empty.  Only after it's finished you pull the wire through.  It's an erector set/LEGO - it's pieces you bolt together.  It's easy to unbolt and change it.  (we're talking EMT).  Worst case, you mis-cut a stick and have to add a coupler somewhere. So you can iterate: test assemble, ask for advice, revise.  Also your work area is small, you don't have to do the whole job in one shot.  When it's finished, suck a rope through and pull your wires.

Comment: @TomGetzinger Yeah I would do 1-1/4".  My automatic go-to for novices is EMT because it's such an erector set... bolt and unbolt at will, so the consequence for mistakes is very low.  PVC is like that if you don't glue it... but then you have zero strength at joints so you must *really* strap it down LOL.   Yes, if the WH doesn't need neutral you don't need to run it, but use a panel with a separate ground bar and leave the neutral bar *conspicuously empty*... so the  "the next guy" doesn't just slap a 120V circuit in there by mistake.

Comment: Ah! So, I can cut EMT on site with a sawzall or hacksaw? I was concerned I needed exact sizes with threads - not happening at my somewhat remote site (~1 hr from supply house). Cool. And thoughts on 1.25" pull elbows (e.g., https://www.walmart.com/ip/1-25-in-Emt-To-Emt-Pull-Elbow/911658859?wmlspartner=wmtlabs&adid=22222222222239811019&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=e&wl1=o&wl2=c&wl3=74560712265228&wl4=pla-4578160278273464:aud-807615483&wl5=&wl6=&wl7=&%20wl10=Walmart&wl12=911658859_10000001205&wl14=1%201%2F4%20inch%20emt%20pull%20elbow&veh=sem&msclkid=35031e7c346f165c84c64114d0416ef2).

Comment: @TomGetzinger you're thinking of Rigid.  EMT is easy, I use one of those mini-hacksaws that gives you a handle to hold a hacksaw blade.  Pull elbows are great if you can access them.  You have to do the pull in segments at that point (which requires access), but it's  more novice-achievable than pulling around multiple bends.  If you want the access cover on back, left or right, look at LB, LL or LR conduit bodies.

Comment: Awesome. Attic is currently accessible, but will some day be full of insulation. Any problem there? LB with access plate pointing up in attic would be more accessible than the pull elbow. Yes, I'd pull in segments.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're on a good track. All access covers must be accessible without needing tools to disassemble any part of the house.  Lifting up some insulation shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I may go EMT, but if I go with orig plan, I'm hoping you can clarify orig ans. 2@6/2+1@8/2 = 4*5+2*3=26 cu in. 4x4x3.5=56 cu in. Even if I double (for wires in+out), I get 52 cu in. Why too big for 4x4? Because of grounds? I can def. go w/ 6x6, just trying to understand. 1" KO = what size clamp connector? 3/4"?

Comment: @TomGetzinger You **need** to double for wires in/out, and you need to count grounds as well (albeit for only 1 wire, so 5 c.i; NEC 2020 revises this to 4 grounds for the price of 1.)  Also, you must use the stamped or published cubic inches, you can't just "make stuff up on the fly".  The Raco 256 box is 45 c.i.  At least pick a Raco 260 which has the KOs you'll need, but even that will be a knuckle skinner. Why not make it easy on yourself?

Comment: Main panel on one side of room. Seems silly to add new subpanel in the same room (except for flexibiity). I think easier is to pick which WH now. E.g., Rheems 27kW has 1-1/4" KO. I could run 1" EMT from main panel all the way to WH and run 6@8 AWG XHHW in the EMT (plus a ground - or use EMT as ground).

Comment: @TomGetzinger Oh yeah, that makes more sense if they're close by... I was assuming clear across the house lol. Yeah the 1" EMT plan is fantastic. Except I made a mistake; I told you wrong on #8 in conduit, because I forgot about a derate.  With 3 circuits in the pipe #8 is only good to 44A.  If the heater's draw is *actually* 44A or less per circuit, then you're fine.  6x#6 just barely meets fill limits for 1" conduit.

Comment: Max draw 112.5A, breakers: 3x40A. wiring: 6x8 AWG + 1 gnd. ~30% fill. Stiebel has one with same specs, except connection is 3x3/4" KOs. So, 3 conduits or a box to split big conduit to 3 smaller. I think I'll go with Rheem.